# Why i can not start the windows service in thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've code which starts depending whether the underlying application runs in console services instead of threads for the tasks. Here is a small cut of the main method:

```
//ANSAR BANK THREAD
Thread AnsarBankThread = new Thread(Ansar);
Console.WriteLine("Start The AnsarBankThread");
AnsarBankThread.Start();
//MELLAT BANK THREAD
Thread MellatBankThread = new Thread(Mellat);
Console.WriteLine("Start The MellatBankThread");
MellatBankThread.Start();
```

This is the code which will be executed:

```
static void Ansar()
{
    var AnsarBank1 = new AnsarBank();
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        AnsarBank1.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]{ AnsarBank1 };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
static void Mellat()
{
    var MellatBank1 = new MellatBank();
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        MellatBank1.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]{ MellatBank1 };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
}
```

and this is my `AnsarBank` service code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // fire every 30 second
    timer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTime;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\Temp\Ansar.txt", "Ansar Bank Writer\n");
}
public void Start()
{
    OnStart(new string[0]);
}
```

And this is my `MellatBank` Service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // fire every 30 second
    timer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTime;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\Temp\MellatBank.txt", "Mellat Bank writer\n");
}
public void Start()
{
    OnStart(new string[0]);
}
```

However, if I run the code there will be only the file `Ansar.txt` created and the file `MellatBank.txt` is missing!
Can someone encounter the problem in my code please? I would appreciate any help!

Chnage code to this:

```
System.Timers.Timer personalTimer = null;

        public AnsarBank()
        {
            personalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // fire every 30 second
            personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTimeAnsar;
            personalTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
```

but so not work.

Comment: Your timer variables are local, and may be being garbage collected. Try turning them into class fields instead.

Comment: I've edited the question. If the edit is accepted it should be readable to more people ;D

Comment: @MatthewWatson Before write this code,write code with one service ,and service run into main thread,and timer not being garbage collected,How can i turning them into class fields?

Comment: @ArthurM. thanks :D

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Seems like you need to practice OOP basics. Please take a look on those again. And according to the edit. No problem! It's a pleasure to help people and it's only heartwarming to correct code :D. Don't forget to accept the edit!

Comment: @ArthurM. Edit ;D

Comment: @MWiśnicki The title should be adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's the problem?

### 1. Variable goes out of scope:

**Thanks to @MatthewWatson**: I also suggest moving the timer variable outside of the method right into the class. The timer object can be garbage collected directly because the garbage collector doesn't see that it's used any further.

***Why thinks the gc that the variable isn't used anymore?***

Simply because you created it in the method. It's local and because the class itself hasn't any reference to it there isn't any hint for the gc that it's needed further!

**This should be true after I looked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880200/windows-service-variable-lifetime) question.**

#### Solution to this in sample code:

```
class SomeClass {
    System.Timers.Timer personalTimer = null; //Timer is now garbage collected after the object of SomeClass goes out of scope!

    SomeClass() {
        personalTimer = new Syste.Timers.Timer(30000) // Now every 30 seconds!
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTime;
        personalTimer.AutoReset = true; //Add this line to keep continuos activation
        personalTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    ....
}
```

### 2.File access problems

After I tried your code I encountered exceptions because the path may not exist. So I changed the code to create a path *before* the creation of a file. Also I added checks whether file exists and if so that text will be applied to the file. The old solution replaced the file everytime. This works for me fine. I don't know what you've done with `InitializeComponents(...)` this seems to be gui stuff, so I don't know.

Change your code in the service classes to following please:

```
    namespace WebService
{
    partial class MellatBank : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer personalTimer = null;


        public MellatBank()
        {
            personalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

            this.ServiceName = "MellatBankService";
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTimeMellat;
            personalTimer.AutoReset = true; //Add this line to keep continuos activation
            personalTimer.Enabled = true;
            //var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // fire every 30 second
            //personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTimeMellat;
            //personalTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OnElapsedTimeMellat(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Temp"))
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Temp\");
                if (!File.Exists(@"D:\Temp\MellatBank.txt"))
                {

                    var f = File.CreateText(@"D:\Temp\MellatBank.txt");
                    f.Write(@"D:\Temp\MellatBank.txt", "Mellat Bank writer\n");
                    f.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    var f = File.AppendText(@"D:\Temp\MellatBank.txt");
                    f.Write("Mellat Bank writer\n");
                    f.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("IO EXCEPTION: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            OnStart(new string[0]);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("ended!");
            // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        }

    }
}


namespace WebService
{
    partial class AnsarBank : ServiceBase
    {

        System.Timers.Timer personalTimer = null;

        public AnsarBank()
        {
            personalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            this.ServiceName = "AnsarBankService";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {


            personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTimeAnsar;
            personalTimer.AutoReset = true; //Add this line to keep continuos activation
            personalTimer.Enabled = true;
            //var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // fire every 30 second
            //personalTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTimeAnsar;
            //personalTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OnElapsedTimeAnsar(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Temp"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Temp\");
                if (!File.Exists(@"D:\Temp\Ansar.txt"))
                {

                    var f = File.CreateText(@"D:\Temp\Ansar.txt");
                    f.Write(@"D:\Temp\Ansar.txt", "Ansar Bank writer\n");
                    f.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    var f = File.AppendText(@"D:\Temp\Ansar.txt");
                    f.Write("Ansar Bank Writer\n");
                    f.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("IO EXCEPTION: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            OnStart(new string[0]);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("ended!");
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

After viewing your code I saw that your services only run as long as your application runs. So your services may have been stopped before they could write anything which would explain your problem too.

---

PS:
Asker please ***practice the basics of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) again*** if you don't know what *class fields* are.